# Filter, search words in string

Tags: php, string, filter

Okay I have the following data:

> liagel - ag, el, li, age, gel, lia

and I'm trying to find a way to get the exact match of the string, you see that all the words exist in the string but I'd like to filter it this way so the final result that I get is:

> liagel = lia gel

Thanks.

Comment: is the match going to be done always in 2 segments

Comment: I don't think I will have more than 3 words within a string. Another example is anarad - ad, an, ar, na, ana, rad ... and yes there might be more than 1 result.

Comment: That example also match made with 2 elements

Comment: But there are two variations, two-word and three-words: an,ar,ad - ana,rad

Comment: so do you want the program to return both variations

Comment: Yes, I suppose I will have longer words with even more than 2 variations.

Comment: Thanks, I just found a solution to my problem.

Comment: you can share it with us by answering your own question

Answer (score 1):

**The Solution:**

I found a quick and easy solution by using the Math Combinatorics library from PEAR http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics/ (the class creates all variations available from the keywords, then I match these variation against my original string and get my final results). Simple code (from 2 words) would look like this:

```
require_once 'library/Combinatorics.php';
$c = new Math_Combinatorics;

$words = array('ag', 'el', 'li', 'age', 'gel', 'lia');
$string = 'liagel';

foreach($c->permutations($words, 2) as $p) {

    $tmp_word = join('', $p);
    $tmp_word_2 = join(' ', $p);

    if ($tmp_word == $string) {

        $found[$string] = $tmp_word_2;
    }
}
```